# FBErrorUtility userMessageForError localization (localisation)

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

When I call
    NSString *message = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];

The message is not being localised. I've got the device language set to French. I also changed the language setting on the Facebook account I used when signing in to French, but the message is still in English.

How do I get the error message localised?

Thanks